# Java Error- Failed to validate the certificate

Tags: java, system-administration

I'm trying to access remote control of my IBM blade center management module through web console but it showing Failed to validate the certificate and unable to start the remote connection. Please check the attached image of error. Please reply if any one have its solution. 
[Click here for screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1Uy9.png)

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: algorithm constraints check failed
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.getValidationState(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.validateChain(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGrantedInt(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.TrustDecider.isAllPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.isTrustedByTrustDecider(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getPermissions(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.defineClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
```

I have also commented this line
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD5, RSA keySize < 1024

and also tried by removing all files from security but still getting the same error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To get meaningful answers, please post the relevant code here instead of posting a link or a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me...

To run JNLP files and start Remote Control Managed sessions not using pre-installed Controller, perform the following steps:

Open the "java.security" file available in the following directory:
[installation_path]\server\java\jre\lib\security\java.security

Locate the "jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms" property and set it to the following value:

MD2, MD5, SHA1 jdkCA & usage TLSServer, 
RSA keySize < 1024, DSA keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 
include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

Save the file and run the downloaded JNLP file.

found it here:  https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sysparm_article=KB0101395

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your response. Finally i got a solution.

1. Remove java.security file from location C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\security (or Program Files depends on your OS). Save this at different location for future reuse.
2. Add the website (which you want to open) in java security Tab of java control panel.
3. Restart your browser and try again.

[java control panel>security>exception_site-list>edit_site_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXTGl.png)

Comment: thank you - your number 1 advice did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your jar file, I would check the more information tag.

These links might help you identify your problem:

At Michltechblog:

http://michlstechblog.info/blog/java-error-failed-to-validate-certificate-the-application-will-not-be-executed/

At MathWorks:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95059-why-do-i-get-an-error-failed-to-validate-certificate-when-running-the-download-agent

Comment: thanks for reply, I tried both options but still getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround when Java fails to validate the certificate.

1. Open `Configure Java` Windows application
2. Click on `Advanced Tab`
3. Find the `Perform signed code certificate revocation checks on` option and change option to `Certificate Revocation Lists (CRLs)`.

[image: Java Control Panel]

Find the `Perform signed code certificate revocation checks on` option and change setting to `Do not check (not recommended)`.

[image: Java Control Panel]

**Security Warning**
After your done with the connection, change the settings back for security reasons.

Choosing the option "Do not check (not recommended)" for signed code certificate revocation checks introduces significant security risks and is considered bad practice.

Disabling certificate revocation checks exposes systems to unnecessary security risks by trusting certificates that may have been revoked due to compromise, association with malicious activity, or other reasons. It's crucial to seek a balanced approach that maintains security without significantly impacting performance or usability.